# How to add developed FB application to the fanspage TAB?

Tags: facebook, fbml

Can any one please let me know how to add developed application to the fanspage TAB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways, but the first step is to enable the application to be installed to tabs.

1. Go to the [developer app](http://www.facebook.com/developers/?ref=sb) and select your application from the list in the right.
2. Click "Edit Settings"
3. Click to the "Facebook Integration" panel
4. Enable the "Facebook Pages" option at the bottom where it says "Installable to?"
5. Save the changes

Then, from this point, you have several options.  Probably the easiest way is to be logged in as a admin of your fan page, then visit the applications profile page - under the logo on the left there's a list of links - one of those is "Add to my Page".  Click that and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following link. Just be sure to change it to your app ID and the url of where the app is hosted.

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL